# Apply bootstraps tr hover effect to a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for my css themes. The themes are compiled and saved into the database for use later on. This means that the pages only have access to the compiled css and not the less files.

Given that, how can I apply Bootstrap’s `tr:hover` effect to various divs? I need the color to be the same as what is defined for `tr:hover` and I can’t use less variables.

Bootstrap's style:

```
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Is it possible to define a css element based on another one that is assigned to a `tr`? Is there a way to grab the style using jQuery?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Pure CSS Way:

Have a class for the `div` as `.hoverDiv` and the CSS for this:

```
.hoverDiv {background: #fff;}
.hoverDiv:hover {background: #f5f5f5;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bD5kS/

#### jQuery Way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hoverDiv").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#f5f5f5");
    }, function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#fff");
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQzwc/

#### To get the colour dynamically, use `$(".table tbody tr:hover").css("background-color")`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hoverDiv").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background", $(".table tbody tr:hover").css("background-color"));
    }, function(){
        $(this).css("background", $(".table tbody tr").css("background-color"));
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know the color until runtime. It's defined in the .table tbody tr:hover element as shown above.

Comment: Okay, in that case, get the colour dynamically this way: Replace `"#f5f5f5"` with `$(".table tbody tr:hover").css("background-color")`.

Comment: perfect and elegant !

Comment: @rboarman I have updated the answer, did you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible - not without javascript.

Using a less variable would be a good option. But if you can't do that, here's the javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/b5DMA/

```
var stylesheets = document.styleSheets,
    stylesheet, new_stylesheet, rules, rule, i = 0,
    max_i = stylesheets.length,
    j, max_j;

for (i = max_i; i--;) {
    stylesheet = stylesheets[i];
    rules = stylesheet.cssRules;
    j = 0;
    max_j = rules.length;

    for (j = max_j; j--;) {
        rule = rules[j];
        if (rule && rule.selectorText.indexOf('.table tbody tr:hover th') > -1) {
            new_stylesheet = document.createElement('style');
            new_stylesheet.innerText = ".el:hover{" + rule.style.cssText + "}";
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_stylesheet);
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: jQuery would be fine. We're not compiling the less files on the fly. THey are precompiled and cached.